# Where can I get some current internet statistics?

Tags: web

During a meeting with a client the topic came up about the internet and where its going in the next 5 years. The client wanted to know stats such as "How many businesses are on the web", "How will my client base increase using the web" and "How can a website benefit my business".

But does anyone have any good articles for this? It would be nice to have some FYI facts, from reliable sources, to reassure them that having a website is a smart business decision.

Answer (score 1):

> During a meeting with a client the
>   topic came up about the internet and
>   where its going in the next 5 years.

You could make some money if you had a good answer for that.  I'll bet you can't tell where it's going in the next five months.

Have some fun - find predictions from five years ago and see how true they are.

> reassure them that having a website is a smart business decision.

Ask them how not having a web site is a smart business decision.  Are you saying they have no presence on the web at all?  How have their sales trended over the last five years?

Don't worry about the web site.  Ask them what their top three business problems are and see how a web site might help it.

Answer (score 0):

For the third question maybe an article about "long tail" could be of interrest. I understand it as making profit with niche market and large user base, but there is many other angles. As usual [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Tail) is a good start and give many other links to reference materiel.